How to get the html element of embed website by mouse event?
Background
I'm going to make a small tool which is able to pick the html element of embed website at the moment I click it(OK, in fact, I just want to make some note in html format other than capturing them while finding something interesting).
Here comes 2 problems: how to embed a website in a document and how to add extra js script to this embed website.
Possible solution?
I try a lot but only find one possible method

use iframe to embed a website in frontend(with vue), whose src refers to a backend route(with python fastapi)
request the url in backend (with python requests)
inject custom js script in response's content(in string format) in backend(with python requests)
return this modified response to frontend(with python fastapi)

Yes, I did it. But it looks sily....
This is the only way that I can escape the effect of X-Frame-Options and CSP.
Any other methods?
